# how to drag circular view in google map iOS Sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode5, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using [Google Map iOS sdk](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) in my iPhone project.I attached one image with this question and i can darw circle but cannot drag circle from one position to another position.I am using following code for drawing a circle.I need view as image shows and also need drag the circular area.Please help me

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.85, 151.20);
GMSCircle *circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:circleCenter
                                         radius:1000];
circ.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor];
circ.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
circ.strokeWidth = 5;
circ.map = mapView;
```

[image]

Comment: Well I believe you should keep changing the coordinate of circle center that will move the circle.Since you have mentioned to move it as per drag action then I dont think it can be achieved and I don't find purpose in doing it.

Comment: Hello @Jasper, did you find any solution ? i also want the same type of functionality. And my radius is not fixed. User can drag,resize, scale the circle

Answer (score 2):

I investigated this for a few hours but no direct solution wasn't found so far. However, I found a way to achieve this. The solution is to clear circle and re-draw a new circle while dragging.

If a circle is drawn around a GMSMaker, dragging circle can be achieved to implement the delegate method that is called while dragging a marker:

```
 -(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didDragMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
     [mapView clear];

     // Re-draw marker
     marker.map = mapView;

     // Create your circle with the new marker
     GMSCircle *circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:marker.position radius:1000];
     circ.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor];
     circ.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
     circ.strokeWidth = 5;
     circ.map = mapView;
 }
```

EDIT:

Note that `[mapView clear]` clears all overlays (include makers). Sometimes it may not be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed radius. Create image in photoshop. Assign it to marker. And set property as draggle to marker. So you will now be able to drag the marker as you want.